# Performing aggregrate queries using Gremlin / TitanDB

Tags: database, graph, gremlin, titan

I have a Titan graph database witha set of vertices connected by an edge with a property named "property1".

Is it possible to write a Gremlin (or anything else Titan would support) query to:

```
Find all edges that have a value for "property1" that is seen 5 or less times.
```

In SQL I would use "Group By", in MongoDB I would use one of the aggregate functions.

I am thinking this may be a job for Furnace/Faunus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by iterating all edges and using `groupBy`.  Here's an example with the toy graph using `weight` in place of `property1`:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g.E.groupBy{it.weight}{it}.cap.next()                         
==>0.5=[e[7][1-knows->2]]
==>1.0=[e[8][1-knows->4], e[10][4-created->5]]
==>0.4=[e[11][4-created->3], e[9][1-created->3]]
==>0.2=[e[12][6-created->3]]
```

So that groups all edges by their `weight`.  From there you can drop down to standard groovy functions like `findAll` to filter out what you don't want (here i filter out weights that have `>1` edge in them...in your case it would be `<5`).

```
gremlin> g.E.groupBy{it.weight}{it}.cap.next().findAll{k,v->v.size()>1}
==>1.0=[e[8][1-knows->4], e[10][4-created->5]]
==>0.4=[e[11][4-created->3], e[9][1-created->3]]
```

Obviously this is a bit of an expensive operation on a really large graph as you have a lot of iteration to do over edges and you have to build up a `Map` in memory which could be big depending on the diversity of the values in `property1`.  If you can find ways to limit edge iteration with other filters, that might be helpful.

This would be a good job for Faunus if you had a really large graph.  I'll go with the easy answer here and simply say that you don't necessarily want the specific edges with a `property1` value occurring less than 5 times and that you just want to know how many times different `property1` values occur.  With Faunus you could get a distribution like that with:

```
g.E.property1.groupCount()
```